# Flume twitter data for specific period

Tags: hadoop, twitter, cloudera, flume

I see that there is a TwitterSource for Flume from Cloudera (com.cloudera.flume.source) to pull the tweets based on a specific keywords but pulls only the current tweets. Is there a way that I can pull tweets based on the keywords as well as for a specific period in time (Ex: for last 3 months)?